# Retrive scheduled time for catchup=true in airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a dag that is scheduled to call a script daily passing the current date so i pass **{{ ds }}** to get the execution date.

On days when my dag doesn't run i have **catchup = True**.
so the dag needs to pass the scheduled date, not the execution date for the task to get done, so that the activity of the day on which the dag was unable to run is still completed.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your scenario, the `execution_date` is exactly what you need.

The name might be a bit misleading, but it is in fact filled with the scheduled timestamp.